# In react-admin, how can i update my current view when i using fetch to get data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, refresh, react-admin

In react-admin, All I know is that the framework provides two ways for me to update, they are setting dataProvider refresh to true and refreshbutton. Now my situation is that I have a **dialog** which used to pay. And the pay request is **not restful** api. So I have to use '**fetch**'. And after pay, How can I **refresh** the current View to get lastest data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import and dispatch Redux action "refreshView" from 'ra-core', example:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/RefreshButton.js

Comment: thx! refresh will return an action,  What I do just to dispath it~

Comment: @MaxAlex do you know where this have been moved to the new versions?

Comment: @Joan React-Admin v4 no longer uses Redux, you can use the hook: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useRefresh.html

Answer (score 1):

please provide more details. Also, view is auto refreshed when state/prop is updated!

In rare cases, forceupdate() can be used